# A Summation Question

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $n$ be an odd integer. If $\sin (n)\theta=\displaystyle \sum _{r=0}^n b_r\sin (r\theta)$, for every value of $\theta$, then

1. $b_0=1, b_1=3$
2. $b_0=0, b_1=n$
3. $b_0=-1, b_1=n$
4. $b_0=0, b_1=n^2+3n+3$

How do I approach it? I am not able to find the values of $b_0$ or $b_1$.

Comment: Use De Moivre's or Euler's formula to evaluate the sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

$$n=1\;,\;\;\theta=0\implies 0=\sin0=b_0+b_1\sin0=b_0$$

and you already ruled out two possibilities. Another one:

$$n=1\;,\;\;\theta=\frac\pi2\implies 1=\sin\frac\pi2=b_0+b_1\sin\frac\pi2\implies\ldots ?$$

Comment: Nice strategy for answering MCQ!

Comment: "MCQ"? What's that? And thanks.

Comment: Multiple Choice Question

Comment: Oh, I see...thanks again.